# Is burning high resolution recordings to CD a bad idea?

Tags: software, mixing, mastering

More and more music is available for purchase / streaming now in Hi-Res formats which exceed CD quality in bit rate or recording frequency.

For practical reasons I often listen to the same music in some places as digital files and as CDs where that it is more convenient.

If I purchase music in a higher resolution format and then burn it as a standard audio CD via something like XLD, is it likely to end up being similar to the recording that was mastered for CD originally? Am I likely to have significant degradation in going from a file that is 24bit/44.1kHz, 24bit/96kHz or 24bit/48kHz to 16bit/44.1kHz?

I know recordings are often made in high bit rate and then mastered for specific formats, but I don't know much about the mix/master process. In this past this was pretty simple since most music for digital purchase was CD-quality, but increasingly I'm finding things that aren't available on CD at all and may only be available in other resolutions.

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to burn music on an audio CD (16/44.1), or as digital files on a data CD (which can be in any format). In the first case you open a bit opinion based audiophile discussion whether the difference between 24/96 and 16/44.1 is audible and what listening conditions are needed to hear the difference. Possibly quality of the conversion is the dominating factor. In the latter case you have an option to preserve the original quality.

Comment: @user1079505 - Great question. I meant a normal audio CD (16/44.1), will update my question to clarify. My question is about the impact of taking a different bit depth / sampling rate and burning it as a standard CD, not whether or not other formats are audibly superior.

Comment: Often the "HiRes" source turns out to be digitally "enhanced" remastering of  something cruddy, in which case downsampling probably doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about consumer home audio and not music practice or theory as outlined in the help center.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Totally fair. Is there a StackExchange community that is a better fit for this question? This seemed like the most appropriate option I could find.

Answer (score 0):

The mastering does certainly not depend on the distribution quality, but it might depend on the "intended listening purpose". In most cases I’d expect a digital download to be the same mastering as you’d expect on the CD though.

Reducing the bit depth is no problem at all. Basically the bit depth tells you how many bits are used to represent the waveform in each specific point in time (that is not exactly true once you get into compression, but we’ll keep it simple). This means reducing bit depth can be simply done be cutting off the least important digits, so it is a very simple operation.

It is slightly more complicated for the sampling rate. This one is how many sample points we get per second. Now suppose the sampling rate is 88.2kHz. Then we could resample this to 44.1kHz simply by only taking each second sample point. The problem is that these high resolution audio files are usually not using multiples of 44.1kHz (CD audio), but of 48kHz (DVD audio). This means that we need to do a more complex kind of resampling.

In the best case this will not change the audio up to rounding noise. But the problem is that this tends to be quite demanding on computational resources, which is why often (especially for replay) simpler and cheaper resampling algorithms are used.

Thus to get the optimal quality onto the CD you should make sure that the audio is resampled well.

Else there is nothing wrong with burning high resolution recordings onto a CD.

Comment: 1. _The mastering does certainly not depend on the distribution quality_ – Mastering **is** a process of preparing the material to be presented on a given medium. 2. _cutting off the least important digits_ – reducing bit depth should be accompanied with dithering to minimize quantization noise. Simple, but not as simple as you present it. 3. Simple _taking each second sample point_ introduces aliasing. There are good techniques of reducing sample rate (and software that just does it right), but they are not what you describe.

Comment: @user1079505 Yes I know. I did not want to get too technical about this, I just wanted to explain why going from 48kHz to 44.1kHz is a costly operation. About 1: I do not think anyone would change the master for 96kHz files. There just is not real reason for it.

Comment: These days as well, there's LUFS to consider. A CD may well still be playing the loudness war ' game' whereas a download will likely conform to -14

Comment: @Tetsujin Everything I've downloaded (or even streamed, if I bothered to check) is at -6 or so, except for one unmastered track from an indie group.  What music are you listening to where -14LUFS is industry standard?

Comment: @Edward - here's a handy beginner's guide to mastering for LUFS levelling. All the big services do it - https://www.masteringthemix.com/blogs/learn/76296773-mastering-audio-for-soundcloud-itunes-spotify-and-youtube

Comment: Seems you've described the method of keeping as much audio quality as possible when converting to audio-CD format.  But I thought the OP's question was more like "will I be able to hear the difference...."

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I've seen all of this information about the "ideal" or "target" loudness many times before.  But, I'm talking about what is actually being done by professionals releasing music.  A download, in my experience, will likely NOT conform to -14.

Comment: @Edward - it can depend on how old it is. More than a couple of years & it will still be loudness-war oriented. If it sits between 10 & 12 it's not going to get murdered by the streaming services, but the older stuff won't have been re-mastered to compensate. I just checked Death Magnetic, which reaches a mind-numbing [& ear-numbing] 3.4 ! Compared to a new Ed Sheeran track at 12. There is every chance these days that the CD & streaming masters are using different constraints.